# Comparing two integers in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show, angular-ng-if

I want to conditionally show or hide an element based on the associated User's `graduation_year` and the `ng-show` and `ng-if` directives aren't working as is.

The element should be shown if the `graduation_year` is greater than or equal to the current year (i.e. the user is "active"), and hidden if less than the current year.

In the view I've tried

```
<div data-ng-repeat="user in data.group.users">    
  <div ng-show="{{ user.graduation_year }} >= {{ date | date:'yyyy' }}">Active</div>
</div>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

but it treats it as false no matter what, even though the output is showing "2017 >= 2015" and "2014 >= 2015" (just a couple examples), so I should be getting different outcomes. When I tried `ng-if`, they were both treated as true no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the variable interpolation incorrectly.

Inside ng-show, you don't need {{ and }}.

Also, you're combining a comparison operation and a filter.
This does work, but it may benefit you to keep the code as visually simple as possible.

Try this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="user in data.group.users">    
  <div ng-show="isActive( user )">Active</div>
</div>
```

and

```
module.controller( 'UserCtrl', [ '$scope', function( $scope ){
    $scope.date = new Date()
    $scope.isActive = function( user ){      
        return user.graduation_year >= $scope.date.getFullYear()
    }
 }])
}
```

Comment: You can, in fact, combine compare with a result returned by a filter - you just need proper parenthesis, like the other answer suggests. So, if you are implying otherwise, this would be an incorrect statement

Comment: @NewDev Learn something new every day, thank you :) Edited to reflect this new knowledge

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces are breaking your code.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="user in data.group.users">    
  <div ng-show="user.graduation_year >= (date | date:'yyyy')">Active</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't really need the curly brackets

Comment: Yep, you're right. In fact it doesn't work when there are curly braces.

Comment: Actually, it does work: `ng-show="{{user.graduation_year >= (date | date:'yyyy')}}"` - it's just not needed

Comment: Ok. It didn't work on the plunkr that I just tested it with. Anyway, there's an answer and it works, so now i'm just going to step away from this... :P